# How to check query string is null if variable is not in url using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check query string variable is null or not.

I have two url before submit:

```
http://localhost/Demotest/index.php?m=admin_controller&t=products&s=backend
```

after submit:

```
http://localhost/Demotest/index.php?m=admin_controller&t=products&s=backend&pid=2045
```

I have check pid in code:

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

But here **pid** is unknown before submit page

Form's action:

```
<form action="<?=$this->config->base_url();?>index.php?m=admin_controller&t=add_product&s=backend&pid=<?=$item->product_id?>" method="post" name="form" >
```

Comment: how are you  passing `pid`?

Comment: i am passing pid when form submit

Comment: how are you generating `pid`?

Comment: use `if($this->input->get('pid'))` to check pid is set or not

Comment: i have added form action to above

Comment: Hey @Saty bro, this is not input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are doing you're not checking to see if something is specifically null, but rather if it's set.  If it's not in the URL, it's undefined.  What you can do is:

```
$pid = null; // set your variable so you can check it later
if (isset($_GET['pid']))
{
    $pid = $_GET['pid']; // set a value if it exists
}

if (!is_null($pid))
{
    // stuff to do with $pid if it was set before
}
```